# Authentication With Custom Token Using Firebase fails

Tags: node.js, angular, firebase, firebase-authentication

Firebase is initialized with multiple apps:-
Node js,server side:-

```
  admin.auth(requiredFile.app).createCustomToken(uid, additionalClaims)
```

In AngularClient-side, I successfully received the token:- Passes the same token as required.

```
firebase.auth(allApps[i]).signInWithCustomToken(token)
        .then((res)=>{
                 console.log(res);
        })
        .catch((error)=>{
            // Handle Errors here.
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
        console.log(error);

        });
```

ERROR SCREENSHOT:-

[image]

Here is the full error text

> Error :-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () base:1 Failed to load googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/…: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404. zone.js:388 L code : "auth/network-request-failed" message : "A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred." proto : Error

I enabled the cors as well in browser(Chrome) but still issue is not resolved.
Can anyone please tell me what's the reason for it?

Comment: Hello, please post the error as text, not as a screenshot

Comment: Correcting my statement:- *firebase is initiallized with multipleApps, not tokens.

Comment: Error :-Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()
base:1 Failed to load https://www.googleapis.com/identitytoolkit/v3/relyingparty/verifyCustomToken?key=AIzaSyAMRkLJs79sB5F8Ett8sqHhOBQKxZGmxks: Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 404.
zone.js:388 
L
code
:
"auth/network-request-failed"
message
:
"A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred."
__proto__
:
Error

Comment: Dont post it into the comments, edit your question

Comment: Hey Nidhi, can you right click on the failing request and copy as cURL? provide the cURL command. You can remove sensitive info like the custom token. This is the best way to recreate this.